# Intel UHD extremely slow copy operations

Tags: opengl, texture, performance, directx11, memory

Is there a way to make copy operations such as `CopyResurce`(d3d11) and `glBlitFramebuffer`(ogl) **on multi-sample resources** faster with Intel UHD integrated graphics?

For Direct3D11 I was able to collect some data (using Intel's graphics frame analyzer), and it looks like a single call to `CopyResource` can take up to **6ms** (both textures being ~**1200x 800, r8g8b8a8_unorm, 8x**).

1. Is it a known issue?
2. Does it mean that it's basically impossible to copy ms textures during the render loop or is there something one could do to make the copy faster?
3. Could that be a driver issue? (I used version 31.0.101.2115 while profiling)